# django form default to ImageField for rendering

Tags: python, django

I have the following Django form:

```
class PageForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    image  = forms.ImageField(required=False)
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols':20, 'rows':10}))
```

I'm using this to create new pages from a given template. But now I want to also add edit possibility, so I would like to use the form to render the same template only with some default values which are retrived from a page id. This is what I have:

```
page_to_edit = Page.objects.filter(id=page_id)[0] // Get page from model
title = page_to_edit.title
content = page_to_edit.content
picture = page_to_edit.picture.order_by('?')[0].file // Here file is a models.ImageField
initial_data = {'title' : title, 'content' : content, 'image' : picture}
form = PageForm(initial_data) 
// Finally return this form to template
```

Now this works as I want for title and content, and those are properly rendered in template with initial values, but the ImageField is just empty. I've also tried passing picture.url instead of picture but no change.

Any help would be appreciated.

All the best

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this the following way:

1. You can use [`.get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get) to retrieve a single record, `Page.objects.get(pk=page_id)`, instead of `.filter()` which returns a queryset. There is also a [shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) `get_object_or_404` that takes a common pattern of wrapping a `.get()` into a `try..except` block for you. If the model is not found, an HTTP 404 page is returned instead.
2. Use a [ModelForm instead](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)
3. A `ModelForm` accepts an `instance` parameter of an existing model so you don't need to set initial values.

With these things in mind your code would end up looking something like this:

```
# forms.py
from django import forms

class PageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Page
        fields = ('title', 'image', 'content')

# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

def edit_page(request, page_id):
    page = get_object_or_404(Page, pk=page_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PageForm(instance=page, request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = PageForm(instance=page)

    return render(request, 'some_template.html', {'form': form})

def create_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PageForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = PageForm()

    return render(request, 'some_template.html', {'form': form})

# urls.py
(r'^page/create/$', views.create_page, 'create_page'),
(r'^page/edit/(?P<page_id>\d+)/$', views.edit_page, 'edit_page'),
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. But what if the form does not match any of the models, but rather 'gathers' parts from more that one model. If my case I simplified the form for the question, but I really have, models: Page, Image, Menu.  Form : PageCMSForm.